# Links are disabled on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, hyperlink

I can't click on any building pictures links (at the very bottom of the homepage) when going on mobile a this project whatever safari, chrome or firefox (while it's working well on desktop) :

- [here is the concerned **building pictures links**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDvpx.png)
  Do you have any ideas of how I can fix that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I can click them on an iPhone 8 with Chrome Browser.
**But** i can only click them *outside* of the colored border. So the colored border is above the image which contains the link.

Check the z-index property and the media queries. You will see, that the border is *above* the image on *mobile devices* and *below* the image on *desktop screens*.